# How to "FillMissing" with a value of 0

Tags: c#, .net, deedle

I'm reading some data in from a CSV file into a frame and I want to replace the blanks in a certain column with zeros. However, when I do `FillMissing(0)`, the series returned still shows the values as blanks. I'm guessing it's because Deedle inferred the type of the column to be `int` and not `int?` and thus a zero is equivalent to missing.

Is there a way to either use `FillMissing` to do what I want, or alternatively, override the type inference so it treats this column as an `int?`?

Answer (score 0):

The `FillMissing` method will fill all missing values in columns that have *the same type* as the value provided. This is a bit confusing and we're looking for better ideas how to do this!

This means that `FillMissing(0)` will only fill columns with integers. You can try calling `FillMissing(0.0)` to handle floating point columns or `FillMissing(0.0M)` to handle decimals.

The fact whether a value is nullable does not matter - Deedle handles missing values directly and so column loaded from a CSV will never have a type `int?`

Comment: That makes sense, but if I do `FillMissing(-1)` it fills the value correctly, so I believe it knows its an integer. Only `FillMissing(0)` fails.

Comment: Huh, that's pretty odd! Can you share a small sample of the CSV file, so that I can reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Sure. How can I send it to you?

Comment: If you are happy to share it publicly, open an issue on Github: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle (it should be possible to replace your actual data with some less sensitive random values...)

Comment: Github won't allow a file upload unless I'm a contributor to the repo.

Comment: Can you put it on, say, pastebin.com and share a link?